# Azure SQL Database - Active Directory integrated authentication

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-server

I would like to achieve following:

Avoid **SQL authentication** on Azure for my production configuration and use **Active Directory integrated authentication**

When I go to the connection string section of Azure and copy following connection string:

```
Server=[my server name];Initial Catalog=[my db name];Persist Security Info=False;User ID=[my user name];MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication="Active Directory Integrated";
```

and try using it I get following exception:

> Exception message: Cannot use 'Authentication=Active Directory
>   Integrated' with 'User ID', 'UID', 'Password' or 'PWD' connection
>   string keywords., Exception stacktrace:    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String
>   connectionString)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String
>   connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey
>   key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions&
>   userConnectionOptions)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey
>   key)

As I have very limited db admin/infrastructure experience I am unaware why the 'User ID' breaks everything when it is explicitly listed in the connection string I get on Azure.

A few things to note:

- SQL authentication works
- I have Active Directory admin set

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your connection string should look like below on C#:

```
string ConnectionString =
@"Data Source=n9lxnyuzhv.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Integrated; Initial Catalog=testdb;";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
conn.Open();
```

Please read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure) documentation and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication) documentation for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Just Try it by removing User ID part in connection string, when you are using

```
Authentication="Active Directory Integrated"
```

```
Server=[my server name];Initial Catalog=[my db name];Persist Security Info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication="Active Directory Integrated";
```

Answer (score -7):

Try changing the IP address in your Azure database. There is a tutorial on [Lynda.com](https://www.lynda.com/SQL-Server-tutorials/Configure-Azure-SQL-Server-firewall/580646/616447-4.html) on this.

Comment: I would assume the exception points to some problem with the connection string.